# Android 7.0 Button ripple effect not updating with button layout changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view, android-button

I am making a productivity app with events that are represented as buttons holding basic information about the event.
The button is contained in a RelativeLayout alongside TextViews, an options menu and a switch. The parent layout's height is set to WRAP_CONTENT. It looks like this:

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/event_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:minHeight="130dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/event_item_title_fontSize"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />

<include
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    layout="@layout/_event_layout_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</include> </RelativeLayout>
```

You can click the button to expand it and show additional information. The expand animation is achieved using a custom animation which updates the button's getLayoutParams().height and calls getParent().requestLayout() every time applyTransformation(...) is called. This works well on an API level 19 (KitKat) device.

Animation code:

```
//The current state of the button which gets updated on animation finish
boolean expanded = false;
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    //Getting references to views
    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) button.getParent();
    final View separator = layout.findViewById(R.id.separator), list = 
layout.findViewById(R.id.notes_list);
    final Button button = (Button) v;
    final RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpl = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) list.getLayoutParams(), 
            lpsw = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) layout.findViewById(R.id.event_switch).getLayoutParams(),
            lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
    //Finished getting references to views
    final int startHeight = lp.height = button.getHeight();
    //Prevents button from automatically resizing to fit its parent when requestLayout is called
    lp.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    layout.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View view, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5, int i6, int i7) {
            layout.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            final int goalHeight = GetExpectedHeight(expanded);
            Animation animation = new Animation() {
                float alpha1 = (expanded ? startHeight : goalHeight) - separator.getTop(),
                alpha2 = (expanded ? startHeight : goalHeight) - list.getTop();
                @Override
                protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                    if (interpolatedTime < 1) {
                        //Updates the button's height
                        lp.height = (int) (startHeight + (goalHeight - startHeight) * interpolatedTime);
                        separator.setAlpha((lp.height - separator.getTop()) / alpha1);
                        list.setAlpha((lp.height - list.getTop()) / alpha2);
                        list.setScaleX(list.getAlpha());
                        list.setScaleY(list.getAlpha());
                        layout.requestLayout();
                        return;
                    }
                    //Animation finish
                    if (expanded) {
                        separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    lp.height = lp.MATCH_PARENT;
                    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.relativeLayout);
                    //A custom method that basically requests layout for whole activity
                    instance.get().Invalidate();
                    expanded = !expanded;
                    this.cancel();
                }
            };
            animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            animation.setDuration(400);
            layout.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
    float alpha = expanded ? 1 : 0;
    separator.setAlpha(alpha);
    list.setAlpha(alpha);
    //Kicks off the onLayoutChange method above
    if (!expanded) {
        separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
        layout.requestLayout();

}
```

However, on an Android 7.0 Nougat (API 24), there is an accompanying ripple effect which overlays the button with a rectangle that doesn't update its height to match the button's height during the animation. I don't know what it looks like on other Android versions because those are the only two devices I can test on. Is there a way to update the ripple effect's rectangle to scale with the button? I would prefer to keep the ripple effect if at all possible. So far I have tried calling performClick() on the button each frame of the animation but to no avail.
Here is a screenshot of the button during expand animation:

[image]

And a video of the animation:
https://streamable.com/vehf3

Comment: i think that if you added your code somebody might fix your problem

Comment: @zombie I hadn't added the code before because it was very large and had some checks that made it untidy and were not really relevant to the animation. But I think you are right so I cleaned it up and added the code.